# Can I change a Form Class action on build?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

On a form classe's `buildForm` method (`AbstractType` derived) can I set the action of that form? 
What I want to do is similar to the `setAction` method that I can use when building an embedded form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
  ->setAction($this->generateUrl('my_action'))
  ->add('field', 'text')
  ->add('button', 'submit');
```

I mean, is the `setAction` an equivalent to form classes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You get access to the same form builder in the `buildForm` method, so just calling the `setAction` on it will work:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->setAction($path);
}
```

The question is how you pass the `$path` to your form type. One of the ways would be to pass it as an option when creating the form. But if you're passing the `$path` anyway, why not just set the `action` itself?

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyType(), $object, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('my_action'),
));
```

Another way would be to inject the router to the form type and use it to generate the URL, but I don't think it's a good idea to make that kind of decisions in a form type.

Comment: I can't upvote yet, as my reputation still doesn't allow it. when it allows, I'll do it ok ?

Comment: Sure, not a problem. It's not a requirement. Just a way to thank an answerer doubly. :)